# ¿Como filtro datos en firebase (web)?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Soy nuevo usando el servicio de `firebase`, pues bien mi pregunta es ¿como puedo filtrar datos?

Es decir si en un `form` escribo texto como hago para que busque el texto de ese `form` en la base de datos y luego me muestre los posibles resultados de mi búsqueda, aclaro que es para una aplicación web por lo que estoy usando `HTML` y `JavaScript`.

Utilizo el siguiente código para poder conectar y ordenar la base de datos en mi proyecto `HTML`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var PalabrasRef = 
database.ref().child('Palabras').orderByKey().limitToFirst(1);
PalabrasRef.once('value', function (snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(item.val()));
  });
});
```

(En síntesis quiero hacer lo de la imagen adjunta solo que obviamente sea visible en la web)

Muchas gracias de antemano !

Answer (score 1):

Para filtrar la información de la Base de datos debes usar una [Query del API de JS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) . Por ejemplo:

```
   var ref = firebase.database().ref("clientes");
   ref.orderByChild("tipo_cuenta").equalTo("principal").on("child_added", 
   function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.key);
   });
```